# SSO via encrypted token

Tags: java, security, jakarta-ee, web-applications

We have the need in a project to implement single sign-on for two different web applications, one being our own and one is implemented by someone else. For our own application we have user/password stored (encrypted) in the database. Since our application will be integrated in their environment, we now need a mechanism to let us authorize the user already being logged in at their side without showing a login screen again.

Since I'm not a security expert myself, I started reading (on a high-level) about a few techniques regarding SSO, e.g. OpenID, Kerberos, SAML, CAS - but I have not yet gained practical experience.

Before marching in the wrong direction - can someone provide me with own experience in that field and point me to a framework to use or a good (and recent) article about how this should be done?

One more infomation: The customer talks about preferring to pass encrypted tokens between the two webapps. Does this make sense? And does this lead to a certain technique?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We use a SAML realization for this purpose ( https://svn.softwareborsen.dk/oiosaml.java/sp/trunk/docs/index.html ) - it was easily integrated inside our existing web applications.

The working scheme can look like as follows: you will have a login page, where the SAML framework redirects user. so, after successful login, he got a cookie with the auth token, and redirected back to the web application page. you will also have an identification webservice, which you can call, passing the token provided, and be able to get the auth credentials (user role, etc) from there, so all your web applications can identify this user as logged in.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I will evaluate this in more detail and it seems an acceptable way to go.